# Block Bootstrapping for synthetic data

Tags: simulations, bootstrapping, synthetic, bootstrap

I am trying Block Bootstrapping for synthetic data generation.

For example in
http://www.blackarbs.com/blog/synthetic-data-generation-part-1-block-bootstrapping
the author @blackarbsceo use data from the iex trading exchange sampled at a 30 sec resolution and apply Block Bootstrapping mentioned above.

The question: how to taking into account the overnight return? The concern is that this big overnight return can appear in the middle of the day.

Comment: Possibly you could generate the overnight returns by sampling from overnight returns and generate the intraday returns by sampling from 30 second blocks of intraday returns.

Comment: Dear @noob2, thank you for the reply. 30 second is the resolution, i.e. we have new data point every 30 sec. How could block be 30 sec then?

Comment: OK, sorry about that, I didn't read whole paper so  did not know the block size. Just delete "30 seconds" from my answer. All I am saying is if you care about overnight returns (some people do not, eg day traders) then generate overnight returns separately from intraday returns (since as you point out they are statistically different).